# Getting a Json from a Mongo query with mongo-java-driver?

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I'm querying my database to get history value between two dates, and i would like to get a json string instead of a FindIterable object.

For now I'm doing like this :

```
public static MongoResponse getHistory(MongoRequest mongoRequest) {
        MongoResponse result = new MongoResponse();
        MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase(mongoRequest.getDbName());
        MongoCollection coll = db.getCollection(mongoRequest.getCollName());
        FindIterable iterable = coll.find(new Document("date", new Document("$gt", mongoRequest.getFromDate())
                .append("$lte", mongoRequest.getToDate()))).sort(Sorts.ascending("date"));
        if (!iterable.iterator().hasNext()) {
            result.setType(MongoResponse.Type.ERROR);
        } else {
            result.setType(MongoResponse.Type.RESPONSE);
            iterable.forEach(new Block<Document>() {
                @Override
                public void apply(Document t) {
                    result.addContent(t.toJson());
                }
            });
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: You should probably use a streaming interface instead of a buffered response to return a collection of data when you aren't limiting the result size. You can very easily blow your heap size if too many history events exist between `getFromDate` and `getToDate`.

Comment: And how do I do that ?

Comment: Well, this method would simply return the `FindIterable` or perhaps a `Iterable<Document>`, and you'd use a streaming serializer such as Jackson to write the response to the file or network socket without buffering the entire output in memory.

Comment: I'm using the websocket protocol for communication, is it possible to send a stream with that ?

Comment: Possible from the protocol perspective, definitely. It would depend highly upon the framework you're using to implement the protocol, though.